# The smallest "non-trivial" amicable pair

Tags: sequences-and-series

All divisors of n except 1 and n itself are also called as "non-trivial" divisors. For example 6 has divisors $1,2,3$, and  $6$, and we call $2$ and $3$ as "non-trivial" divisors of $6$. Here I'm looking for amicable pairs which I call as "non-trivial" amicable pair. So a pair of 2 distinct positive integers (m,n) is called a "non-trivial" amicable pair if:

- The sum of all "non-trivial" divisors of m equals n
- And the sum of all "non-trivial" divisors of n equals m.

I have checked numbers up to $1000$ , but I couldn't find such amicable pair. Is there any "non-trivial" amicable pair ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed $m=48,n=75$. $$2+3+4+6+8+12+16+24=75,\quad3+5+15+25=48$$ These pairs are discussed in Lal and Forbes, [A note on Chowla's function](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1971-25-116/S0025-5718-1971-0297685-X/S0025-5718-1971-0297685-X.pdf), Mathematics of Computation Vol. 25, No. 116, October 1971, 923-925.

See also https://oeis.org/A003502 and the reference given there.